Nifty50 data science project in python Error occuring KeyError: 'Date'
I am working on Nifty50 dataset as my Data science project but this error occurs when I'm trying to implement datetime. Please help me?
This is my code to change Date which is an object into datetime:
nfty50_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(nifty50_data['Date'])

but that error occurs:

KeyError: 'Date'


This means that nfty50_data does not have a field called "Date". A KeyError means that the key does not exist, i.e., you cannot access it.

From where do you get the dataset?
Please also include the rest of the code

the Nifty-50 data set consists of ~50 distinct csv files - which have you opened and loaded ? show your code please. EG: pd.to_datetime(data['Date'][0]) gives me Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00') for a dataset read in., once we see your code then feedback can be tailored to that.

@ticktalk 1 -NIFTY 50-05-06-2023-to-05-06-2024.csv . Dataset Link : https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shreyaskeote23/nifity-50

@DaSt Dataset link : https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shreyaskeote23/nifity-50

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@VanshChauhan, i gave a response - in the answer below. you  need to remove (trim) the space from each field (ideally in the input file or deal with them having a trailing space, it should be relatively simple to fix. Unless there's something else you need to elaborate on

too long to comment ....
all of the field names have a trailing space (excepting the last)'
#output from nifty50.columns:
Index(['Date ', 'Open ', 'High ', 'Low ', 'Close ', 'Shares  Traded ','Turnover (₹ Cr)'],dtype='object')

# so using either 
# (the first throws a warning about format but works fine)

nifty['Date '] = pd.to_datetime(nifty['Date ']) 

#or 

nifty['Date '] = pd.to_datetime(nifty['Date '], format='%d-%b-%Y')


hope this helps.

fyi, search online) how to rename columns in a dataframe .... df.rename(columns= .....
